# Get CodeIgniter Controller methods names from a CodeIgniter Library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to get `CodeIgniter` controller methods names from a codeigniter Library.

I figured i can't include the controller file inside the Library to create a new instance, because `codeigniter` has it yet loaded.

The plan was to pass the controller instance to the `PHP reflectionClass` to fetch every `public` method.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) should help you accomplish this, however I'm not sure if you've already tried it, or if you've tried anything else for that matter.

Comment: doesn't it wants class instance too?

Comment: it does but you can use `if(!class_exists($className))require_once('../controllers/controller_name'); $temp = new $className;$methods = get_class_methods($temp);`

Comment: I can't because every controller (class) is autoloaded by codeigniter. I need another method.

Comment: Nevermind, solved using your hint. Thanks so much.